# Angular Universal with api internal express calls

Tags: node.js, angular, express, universal

I have checked several tutorials and walkthroughs on how to add SSR (server-side rendering) to existing angular CLI & Express projects.

I was able to run node with SSR but I'm unable to make API calls.
I wish to run one node process that can serve static file (Angular with SSR) and dynamic content with API calls which access *SQLITE* DB using *KNEX*.

This is my *server.js* file

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'bin/dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./bin/dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, ''));

// import * as apiS from './server/index';
// apiS.load(app);
// TODO: implement data requests securely
// app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
//   res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
// });

import * as LoadRoutes from './server/boot/routes';
LoadRoutes.load(app);


// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, '')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Is it even possible to accomplish SSR + API calls from the same node process and if so can someone post here answer?

Answer (score 4):

It's already there. Just uncomment these lines and extend the API routes with Express router:

```
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});
```

Use the router file instead:

```
app.use('/api/*', appRoutes);
```

Every URL starting with api/ will be served by backend APIs.